# Best software to import finances

Tags: loans, software, accounts, transaction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best software tools for personal finance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/what-are-the-best-software-tools-for-personal-finance)

I'm looking for a tool to manage my personal finances with. I've got various loans, credit cards, a few investments, and some open accounts at different banks.

I would prefer an open source solution, but I am willing to get an alternative if it fulfills my needs. I've already looked at [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/2301/7920), and none of the solutions therein fixes my most important problem.

In this day and age of software and account activity exports, I don't want to have to manually enter in individual receipts as if I was using a checkbook. Every month or so I want to import a QFX/QIF/CSV file and have the thing happily updated.

GnuCash sort of works, but it has so much going on that finding things proves difficult. Also, every single import wants approval and checking over of everything. I got it from the bank, I skimmed it, and I want the software to happily fill in everything else. If necessary, I can rearrange the other side of the double entry system if an entry gets into the wrong spot.

Concisely, I don't want my finances to be *work*, where I go over a month of receipts and decide if this goes into gas or vacation expenses.

Is there some software that fills this hole, or do they all assume you will be going over every transaction all the time?

Comment: I'll have to vote to close as duplicate to the very same question you linked to. You will not get any other answers than what's there already.

Comment: @littleadv If so, then that's fine. I had hoped that my question was more specific on what I desired, and why.

Comment: You are describing Quicken.  There are a ton of bad reviews, but you have to consider how much market share Intuit has.  Quicken is your answer.

Comment: Regarding your comment "every single import wants approval and checking over of everything." concerning GnuCash, I developed https://github.com/Kraymer/qifqif that makes qif imports instantaneous as you would expect. The "secret" is to have categories filled in with accounts names.